# ASP.NET 4.5 Won't Uninstall from Windows 8

Tags: asp.net, windows, windows-8, asp.net-4.5, iis-8

I have been running into compatibility issues recently with my dev environment, and it was suggested that I uninstall and reinstall ASP.NET 4.5 on my windows 8 laptop.

In order to uninstall on Windows 8, you must use the "Turn Windows Features On/Off" feature.

When I perform the uninstall, everything seems fine, but when I go to reinstall .NET 4.5, I get the following error message from the installer.

[image]

I'm not sure how else to ensure a complete uninstall of the 4.5 runtime. Is this a Windows 8 problem?

Comment: Maybe some part of the system is use the net, maybe the new explorer ?

Comment: @CitadelCSAlum I am from .NET Framework compatibility team. I would like to understand more about compatibility issues that you're seeing. Can you email me at netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com with information on any compatibility issues that you may be seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net 4.5 is a core part of the windows 8 operating system and cannot be removed.

You can remove ASP.Net 4.5 through add/remove windows features and it can be turned back on there as well.

If there truly is an issue with .Net 4.5 on your Windows 8 install which possible but unlikely you would need to repair the OS.